# Why does Glassfish localhost:8080 have Tomcat favicon?

Tags: tomcat, glassfish

I startedGlassfish. On port 4848 `localhost:4848`   it has    the Glassfish  favicon. The admin dashboard looks amaizing

However, when I pasted this `localhost: 8080` in the browser, I saw the very familiar Tomcat favicon.

Why is it so ?

In the server.log there is `catalina`, and `apache` it looks so much similar to Tomcat

Is Tomcat a part of Glashfish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat is not part of glassfish and they have not much in common. Perhaps just a few libraries that are used by both (have not checked).

The favicon that shows up in your browser is cached from the previous Tomcat installation that you had running. Try clearing the browser cache or use another browser and check the icon again.

Comment: Actually, the web server in GlassFish was originally Tomcat and maintained as such. The Tomcat code in GlassFish diverged, though, and is now maintained completely separately, hence why there is catalina code in the source.

Comment: Aha! Here you go `catalina`